# Concat string variable and integer variable

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, for-loop, concatenation

I have a form with 12 groupbox and each of that groupbox there is 3 radio buttons.
I use `for loop` to get what radio button is checked and get the value of radio button.
I declare string and integer variables to go through groupboxes and radiobuttons. My problem is how to concat string variable and integer variable. sample code :

```
 Dim opt, opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4, opt5, opt6, opt7, opt8, opt9, opt10, opt11, opt12 As String
    Dim grpboxcnt As Integer = 1
    Dim rdbtncnt As Integer = 1
    Dim xrdbtn As String

    For Each grpbx As GroupBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of GroupBox)()

        For Each rdbtn As RadioButton In Me.Controls("GroupBox" & grpboxcnt).Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)()
            If rdbtn.Checked = True Then
                If rdbtn.Text = "Yes" Then
                    opt & rdbtncnt = 1 '(i want to be like this way but it is an error and it is not the proper way, is there any way to concat string variable to integer variable?) if this is checked i want to concat the string(opt) and integer(rdbtncnt) example opt & rdbtncnt = 1 ;but it gives me error 
                ElseIf rdbtn.Text = "No" Then
                    opt & rdbtncnt = 0 '(i want to be like that but it is an error and it is not the proper way, is there any way to concat string variable to integer variable?) if this is checked then i want to concat the string(opt) and integer(rdbtncnt) example opt & rdbtncnt = 0 ;but it gives me error
                ElseIf rdbtn.Text = "NA" Then
                    opt & rdbtncnt  = 2 '(i want to be like that but it is an error and it is not the proper way, is there any way to concat string variable to integer variable?) if this is checked i want to concat the string(opt) and integer(rdbtncnt) example opt & rdbtncnt = 2 ;but it gives me error
                End If
            End If
            Next
         rdbtncnt += 1 'then rdbtncnt increment new set of radiobuttons will be looped
        grpboxcnt += 1 'then grpboxcnt increment new name of groupbox will be looped
    Next

sqlcommand.commandType = "UPDATE table1 SET radio1 = @opt1, radio2 = @opt2 , radio2 = @opt3 , etc... WHERE tableID = 1"
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to create a variable name at runtime?  I.e., if opt1 is set to 1, in the first group you want to set create a variable named `opt11` with a value of 1? You can't create variable names at runtime.  Couple of question to help you get an answer - what is the error you are currently getting, and what are you ultimately trying to do with the variables you're trying to create?

Comment: check updated post(comment part)

Comment: @ReignOfRayn25 - short answer is you can't do what you're trying to do (at least as far as I'm aware); however, check my answer for an alternative approach that might work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to do - it sounds like you want to use the correct `opt` variable based on which `RadioButton` you're in - i.e., if you're in `RadioButton1`, you want to use `opt1`, if you're in `RadioButton2` you want to use `opt2`, etc.

Unfortunately, you can't refer to a variable by concatenating two different variables to form it's name - at least, not that I'm aware of.

There's a couple of ways around this - you could use a `List(Of Integer)` to hold the value in the same order as the `RadiButton`s, or you could use a `Dictionary(Of String, Integer)` to hold the name as the key ("opt" & RadionButton number) and the value you select.

Since you appear to intend to use this to provide values for parameters to SQL command, I'd recommend the dictionary, since you can get the correct value by passing in the parameter name as a key:

```
Dim radioButtonValues As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
Dim grpboxcnt As Integer = 1
Dim rdbtncnt As Integer = 1

For Each grpbx As GroupBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of GroupBox)()

    For Each rdbtn As RadioButton In Me.Controls("GroupBox" & grpboxcnt).Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)()
        If rdbtn.Checked = True Then
            If rdbtn.Text = "Yes" Then
                radioButtonValues.Add("@opt" & rdbtncnt.ToString(), 1) 
            ElseIf rdbtn.Text = "No" Then
                radioButtonValues.Add("@opt" & rdbtncnt.ToString(), 0)
            ElseIf rdbtn.Text = "NA" Then
                radioButtonValues.Add("@opt" & rdbtncnt.ToString(), 2)
            End If
        End If
     Next
     rdbtncnt += 1
     grpboxcnt += 1
Next
```

This creates a Dictionary with "@opt1" as the key for the first `RadioButtonList`, "@opt2" for the second `RadioButtonList`, etc. I added "@" to the key because you'll use that as the parameter name in the following code:

```
' Note that it should be CommandText, not CommandType
sqlcommand.CommandText = "UPDATE table1 SET radio1 = @opt1, radio2 = @opt2 , radio2 = @opt3 , etc... WHERE tableID = 1"
sqlcommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text

For Each key As String in radioButtonValues.Keys

    sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(key, radioButtonValues(key))
Next
```

Essentially, for each keyvalue pair in the dictionary, you add the key as the parameter name and it's value as the parameter value to the SQL command's parameter collection.

**NOTES**

This is a little brittle, as you have to make sure you SQL Statement has the right number of parameters and they're named correctly.  You could extend the code above to create the SQL command based on the keys in the dictionary and then add the parameters, but you'd wind up going through the dictionary twice, not once (once to build the SQL, a second time to build the parameters collection).

Also, you're incrementing `rdbtncnt` and `grpboxcnt` in the outer loop, and I'm not sure that's what you want (unless you know that there's only one `RadioButton` in each `GroupBox`).

Comment: sir last question. its the same problem but what if its a control.. heres the link sir :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18248989/how-to-concat-variable-integer-in-control-name-in-vb-net/18249088?noredirect=1#18249088

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

**rdbtncnt2Str = rdbtncnt.ToString()**

or

**rdbtncnt2Str = Convert.ToString(rdbtncnt)**

This will convert the integer into string ,then you can concat using:

**Dim result As String**

**result = opt & rdbtncnt**

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim opt, opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4, opt5, opt6, opt7, opt8, opt9, opt10, opt11, opt12 As String
    Dim grpboxcnt As Integer = 1
    Dim rdbtncnt As Integer = 1
    Dim xrdbtn As String
    Dim result As String
    For Each grpbx As GroupBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of GroupBox)()

        For Each rdbtn As RadioButton In Me.Controls("GroupBox" & grpboxcnt).Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)()
            If rdbtn.Checked = True Then
                If rdbtn.Text = "Yes" Then
                    opt1 = 1 

                ElseIf rdbtn.Text = "No" Then
                    opt1 = 0 
                ElseIf rdbtn.Text = "NA" Then
                    opt1 = 2 
                End If
                rdbtncnt2Str = rdbtncnt.ToString()
                result = opt1 & rdbtncnt2str
            End If
            Next
         Integer.TryParse(result, rdbtncnt)
         rdbtncnt += 1 
        grpboxcnt += 1 
    Next

sqlcommand.commandType = "UPDATE table1 SET radio1 = @opt1, radio2 = @opt2 , radio2 = @opt3 , etc... WHERE tableID = 1"
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: nope.. it didn't work.. anyways thank you.. i use the long method.