# How to concat variable integer in control name in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, for-loop, user-controls

Now I have a database and pull out that data and display it to form,i have a sequence of groupbox and radiobuttons, in each groupbox (groupbox1,groupbox2,etc...) there are 2 radio buttons namely rdbtn1Yes and rdbtn1No (then it increment +1 in next Groupbox). now i use `for loop` to go through every groupboxes and radio buttons. And this is my code:

```
    Dim sqlda As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1= '" & lblWONo.Text & "'", Constr)
    Dim sqlds As New DataSet

    sqlds.Clear()
    sqlda.Fill(sqlds)

    If sqlds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then

        With sqlds.Tables(0).DefaultView.Item(0)

            txtDateCreated.Value = .Item(0).ToString
            txtComments.Text = .Item(1).ToString

            'check column if it contain FALSE/TRUE value
            'then toggle the radiobutton state to TRUE

            'In this part i know there is another/easiest way to checked radio buttons to TRUE value 
            'and this is my code using looping (below):

            If .Item(2) = False Then
                rdbtn1No.Checked = True
            Else
                rdbtn1Yes.Checked = True
            End If

            If .Item(3) = False Then
                rdbtn2No.Checked = True
            Else
                rdbtn2Yes.Checked = True
            End If

            If .Item(4) = False Then
                opt3N.Checked = True
            Else
                opt3Y.Checked = True
            End If
        End With
    End If
```

SAMPLE CODE FOR LOOPING:

```
            Dim itemNo As Integer
            Dim rdbtnSet As Integer = 1
            Dim grpboxCnt As Integer = 1

             For Each grpbx As GroupBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of GroupBox)()
                For itemNo = 2 To sqlds.Tables(0).Columns.Count

                    If .Item(itemNo) = True Then
                        rdbtn & rdbtnSet & "Yes".checked = True 'I want to be this way but we know that this is not working or its not the proper way. That is my problem.
                    Else 
                        rdbtn & rdbtnSet & "No".checked = True 'I want to be this way but we know that this is not working or its not the proper way. That is my problem.
                    End If

                Next
                 rdbtnSet += 1
                 grpboxCnt += 1
             Next
```

Thats all. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Think about the use of a dictionary (id, control) to store your controls. Then iterate the dictionary and set your state.

Comment: could you provide an example??

Comment: On way is to store it in a kind of triple: 

(pseudo code) 

{ .Item(2), rdbtn1No, rdbtn1Yes.Checked; .Item(3), rdbtn2No, rdbtn2Yes.Checked; ... } (feel free to find a collection which suites best for you) then write a loop which iterates the collection. 

By the way a would kill the if-statements: 

opt3Y.Checked = .Item(4) and 
opt3N.Checked = Not opt3Y.Checked.

Comment: @ReignOfRayn25: Would be nice if you can give some feedback